# Setting up a hierarchical model using R2jags

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, r2jags, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm working on a project for an introductory Bayesian analysis course and I'm also fairly new to using R regularly.  We are supposed to build a hierarchical model using a data set we found or put together.  I put a data set together to analyze the question of how much a nations social freedoms and its wealth affect its happiness.  The data set looks like this:

```
      Country Country.ID Year Happiness.Score   GDP.PPP Status
1 Afghanistan          1 2015           3.575  1766.593      1
2 Afghanistan          1 2016           3.360  1757.023      1
3 Afghanistan          1 2017           3.794  1758.466      1
4     Albania          2 2015           4.959 10971.044      2
5     Albania          2 2016           4.655 11356.717      2
6     Albania          2 2017           4.644 11803.282      2
```

Status is taking from Freedom House that I converted into an integer, `1` means not free, `2` means partly free, and `3` means a free society. For my first model, I don't want to add the GDP data.

I put together code that looked the same as an example we saw in class, but I've run into trouble, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is how I set everything up from making lists, to modeling, setting up priors, and running the `jags` command:

```
#Making lists and assigning loop numbers
Num.Obs <- 460
Country <- impute.set1[,2]
Year <- impute.set1[,3]
Happiness.Score <- impute.set1[,4]
GDP.PPP <- impute.set1[,5]
Status <- unique(impute.set1[,6])
Num.Status <- 3

#Modeling
model1 <- function(){
  #Data Model
  for (i in 1:Num.Obs){
    #Observations at Country Level
    Happiness.Score[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau.Happiness.Score)
    #Random Intercept and slope(alpha is intercetp, beta1 of country and time)
    mu[i] <- alpha[Country[i]] + beta1[Country[i]]*Year[i]
  }
  #Priors
  for (j in 1:Num.Status){
    alpha[j] ~ dnorm(mu.alpha, tau.alpha)
    beta1[j] ~ dnorm(mu.beta1[Status[j]], tau.beta1)
  }
  mu.alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  tau.alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  sigma.alpha ~ dunif(0, 10)

  mu.beta1[1] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  mu.beta1[2] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  mu.beta1[3] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  tau.beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  sigma.beta1 ~ dunif(0, 10)

  tau.Happiness.Score ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  sigma.Happiness.Score ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
}

#Listing my lists and parameters I want to save for final use
MyVars1data <- list(Country=Country, Year=Year, Status=Status, Happiness.Score=Happiness.Score,
                    Num.Obs=Num.Obs, Num.Status=Num.Status)
params <- c("mu.alpha", "mu.beta1[1]", "mu.beta1[2]", "mu.beta1[3]", "sigma.Happiness.Score")

#Implement Jags
m1 <- jags(MyVars1data,
           model.file = model1,
           parameters.to.save = params,
           n.chains = 3,
           inits = NULL,
           n.iter = 10000,
           n.burnin = 5000,
           progress.bar = "text")
```

I end up with an error that looks like this:

```
Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 5.
Index out of range taking subset of  alpha
```

I have 460 observations in my data set. I'm looking through the loops I made and I think `i` should be going from 1 to 460.  I believe the error is here: `mu[i] <- alpha[Country[i]] + beta1[Country[i]]*Year[i]` Am I looking at the wrong place?

Can anyone help me to debug this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is Country converted to nuemric ? If you use it as index, they shoud be integer or numeric. I didn't try but feel `Country <- as.numeric(as.factor(master.set[,1]))` solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, I did make that change and tried to re-edit this to give more of an update on how my data set look.  I created the `Country.ID` variables as an integer variable and created the list `Country <- impute.set1[,2]`.  This ended up having giving me an integer list of `[1:460]`. So, it looks right to me.  But, I must be missing something.

Comment: In Data Model, you assume that alpha and beta depend on Country (e.g., `alpha[Country[i]]`) but in prior, they depend on Status. in other words, you provide alpha and beta, three length vectors, but your model needs the length of vector is the same as Country num. Maybe your code run with `mu[i] <- alpha[Status[i]] + beta1[Status[i]]*Year[i]` (but I feel it isn't what you want).

Comment: It's not exactly what I want, but I tried it anyway to see if it would work.  I end up getting a slightly different message. `Index out of range taking subset of  Status`.

Comment: I made the changes and I now get a new error: 
`Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  Error in node beta1[1]
Invalid parent values`

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot Status is uniqued. Please use `Status2 <- impute.set1[,6]` and `mu[i] <- alpha[Status2[i]] + beta1[Status2[i]]*Year[i]` (and change related part.) (edited, maybe you guessed)